# Combine Weather state with User Activity state

Tags: android, google-awareness

I have a use-case wherein a notification will be issued when the weather is sunny, user activity is walking and there's also a particular location. How should i go about combining these three conditions?

I know that we can use `AwarenessFence.and()` to add multiple fences but since we would be getting the weather data from the Snapsot API, how can we add that condition in the Fence API.

I am sure someone would have faced the same problem before and solved it. Please share your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Awareness API does not yet support creating fences based on Weather context.
As you have mentioned, you can create AwarenessFence for location and activity, and then combine them with `AwarenessFence.and()` or `AwarenessFence.or()`.

If you'd like weather to be included in your criteria for notifications, one thing you can do is to request the weather snapshot when you receive the fence callback on the intent, and then initiate notification if the weather matches your target conditions.

For example, borrowing directly from code snippets in the [Awareness API guide](https://developers.google.com/awareness/),

```
public class MyFenceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      FenceState fenceState = FenceState.extract(intent);

      if (TextUtils.equals(fenceState.getFenceKey(), "headphoneFence")) {
        switch(fenceState.getCurrentState()) {
            case FenceState.TRUE:
                WeatherResult weatherResult = 
                  Awareness.SnapshotApi.getWeather(mClient).await();
                if (weatherResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                  Weather weather = weatherResult.getWeather();
                  if (myDesiredWeather(weather)) {
                    sendNotification();
                  }
                }
                break;
            case FenceState.FALSE:
                Log.i(TAG, "Headphones are NOT plugged in.");
                break;
            case FenceState.UNKNOWN:
                Log.i(TAG, "The headphone fence is in an unknown state.");
                break;
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Admittedly this is a bit of a roundabout way of achieving what you want, but it seems the only way to solve your use-case.